# How to excute java.class in any folder?

Tags: java, javac

This is my folder:

```
$ tree
.

├── src
│   ├── Main.class
│   ├── Main.java
│   └── xyz
│       └── bitfish
│           ├── Fish.class
│           └── Fish.java
```

if I try to excute Main.class in current folder, it will fail:

```
$java src/Main
Error: Could not find or load main class src.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main (wrong name: src/Main)

$ java src.Main
Error: Could not find or load main class src.Main
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Main (wrong name: src/Main)
```

But if I try to do this in src folder, it will be fine

```
$ cd src
src$ java Main
// it works
```

What is the problem? How to excute Main.class in any foler?

Comment: Use java -cp src Main

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try using the command:

java -classpath src Main

when you give the command

java src/Main  --> then java not only tries to use the class in src folder; but it also assumes that the package is src.Main ;  and so trying to execute it that way will give you an error; unless the class defined by Main.java --> Main.class is in package "src" apart from being in directory src.

Answer (score 3):

When you run `java -help`, you get this output:

```
Usage: java [options] <mainclass> [args...]
           (to execute a class)
...
```

This short message says `<mainclass>`, and by that it means "the fully qualified name of the Java class, regardless of where it is saved in the file system".

When you run `java src.Main` or `java src/Main`, you tell the `java` command to run the class `src.Main`, which doesn't exist anywhere in the classpath.

To fix this, set the classpath to `src` (since that's where the `.class` files are), and then run the class called `Main`:

```
java -classpath src/ Main
```